# "J'en ai le droit d'aimer" - pourquoi le pronom "en" ?

Tags: pronoms, en

> J'en ai le droit d'aimer.
>
> J'en ai le droit...

*Le droit d'aimer* par Edith Piaf

`J'en ai le droit` signifie `I have right for this`. Je comprends pourquoi le pronom `en` est utilisé ici.

Mais pourquoi c'est le cas dans la première phrase? J'ai trouvé beaucoup d'examples `j'ai le droit de (infinitif)` sans `en`.

Comment: Le *'en'* renvoie à ce qu'Édith Piaf a cerné comme obstacle ou expérience avant d’affirmer son droit. « Tout ce que je viens de dire me donne le droit d’aimer, *aimer* n’est pas réservé qu'aux autres, c'est aussi ce que je revendique. », ce *droit* ne relève pas de la justice, mais de l'Amour … à la fin de la chanson cet amour réclame la réciprocité. Le regard des artistes ne porte pas sur les concepts, mais sur la conscience de la Vie, de ce qu’ils peuvent en attendre, et leur révolte contre les injustices est une des sources de leur inspiration.

Comment: Merci pour une explication des sentiments d’Edith Piaf, mais je m’intéresse plutôt à la grammaire utilisée dans cet exemple. « En » remplace « de cela », mais dans « j’en ai le droit d’aimer », on dit directement « d’aimer ». Alors, on n’a plus besoin du pronom « en », n’est-ce pas ?

Comment: Ce n’est pas une question de grammaire, mais de sens : « J'ai le droit d'aimer » ce droit est inhérent à mon être, à la nature humaine, aucune société ne peut l’interdire, même si elle refuse que cet amour se réalise, alors que dans « J'en ai le droit d'aimer » me donne le droit de réaliser cet amour dans cette même société. NB : la grammaire imposée par l'Éducation Nationale a été un obstacle à mon apprentissage de l’anglais, qui se limite à "l’airport English", et je suis incapable de faire une analyse grammaticale en français, …

Comment: … c’est la philologie (si chère à Nietzsche) qui m’a ouvert à une connaissance plus fine de ma langue maternelle et à une connaissance du fonctionnement de la parole, quelle que soit la langue utilisée, l'oralité n'est jamais loin avec le travail du théâtre (sans être comédien) où la manifestation des sentiments et émotions reste le principal centre d’intérêt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 possible explanations:

1) The *en* is a pronoun that means "because of that, on basis of what was said before*. *J'en ai le droit d'aimer* means then "I have the right to love because of all of this*.
A less literary and more mundane form would be: *en raison de tout ce que je viens de citer, j'ai le droit d'aimer*.

2) the *en* is a pronoun that replaces *d'aimer*. The syntax can be surprising as the pronoun precedes the word it replaces, and as the referent is then repeated and seems redundant. It is a turn of phrase that can be found in the flow of a conversation in spoken French.
Ex:

> J'en ai beaucoup, des livres.
>
> Il m'en a parlé, de sa soeur.

Note that in a written transcription, it is then appropriate to add a comma before the repetition of the referent, which I do not see in transcripts of the lyrics of the song (but...I have seen many incorrect lyrics transcripts on the web).

It has even become the standard form for some fixed phrases like *en avoir marre de*, *en avoir assez de*, etc.

Another element you should keep in mind whatever interpretation you choose: for song lyrics, there is also the constraint of euphony and of the number of feet that needs to match the music. Maybe the lyricist just felt *j'en ai le droit d'aimer* sounded better on this melody that the standard *j'ai le droit d'aimer* and simply used his "poetic licence".